# Check whether a directory contains any files

Tags: c#, string, file, directory

```
 DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path);

 if()   // there is a file in the directory do something.
```

I can get the files if there exists any, but I also have to consider the possbility that there is no file inside that subfolder path.

Comment: If there is no file then I suspect `d.GetFiles()` would return an empty result.

Comment: It returns an error, I don't know why.

Comment: using `if (d.EnumerateFiles.Any()) { // there are files` would remove the need to retrieve all the files.

Comment: Reading the error would be a good start.

Comment: Did you check if the directory exists?  And that you have permission to read it?

Answer (score 7):

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path);
if (files.Length == 0)
    Console.WriteLine("Empty");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not Empty");
```

Using `EnumerateFiles`

```
 var fileCount = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\").Count();
 if (fileCount == 0)
    Console.WriteLine("Empty");
 else
    Console.WriteLine("Not Empty");
```

Comment: Calling EnumerateFiles instead would be more efficient

Comment: The problem is Directory.GetFiles(path) method is not correct when the folder contains no files.

Comment: @CemAytekin No it works! which folder you want to check?

Comment: If you use the `Count` property on the result of `EnumerateFiles()`, you might as well call `GetFiles()` - whereas `EnumerateFiles.Any()` can short-circuit after the first file is returned.

Comment: Okay, it turns out that if there is no file in the folder ,program says the directory does not exist.

Comment: Are you getting a "DirectoryNotFoundException"?  Possibly because the directory does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

If there are no files the following will return an empty string array:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no files in a folder that exists, you'll get an empty collection:

[image: exists]

> .
>
> .

If the folder that you are looking for does not exist, you'll get this exception instead:

[image: doesnotexist]